# Python not finding files to import in same folder

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to create a folder with methods to implement across a larger project, however python doesn't seem to be able to find the file I have created for this. I want to import 'staging.methods.py' similarly to how I've imported the 'staging.constants' file from the same folder(which works fine), however the file does not show up on the dropdown and is unrecognized. The file is also greyed out on the left hand side along with other files with the same problem.
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Z6m.png)

I've tried various ways of labelling the import, none of which I expected to work because the way I am doing it in the image should be viable and I can't see a reason why it wouldn't be

Comment: If the file you're importing is in the same folder as the file you're doing the import in, then specifying the folder name is redundant and incorrect.

Comment: Is the problem specific to a particular IDE? Can you reproduce it in a different environment?

Comment: Random Davis - except if i remove it then it won't even recognise the constants file so that was the only way I could get it to work and that comment does not help me solve my problem

Comment: Ignatius Reilly - it looks like it works in Pycharm, thanks for the suggestion